# Create a CSS Less Mixin for Responsive Grid with Pocket Grid

Tags: css, less, pocketgrid

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">    
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://placehold.it/400x200"/></div>
</div>
```

And I am using [PocketGrid](http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/) to have a responsive grid. I created an [Example](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/AyaCt/)

My LESS code is the following:

```
.wrapper {

  &:extend(.block-group);

  background-color: red;

  div {
    &:extend(.block);

    background-color: green;

    img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      outline: 0;
    }
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) { 
 .wrapper div {
   width: (100% / 2);
  }
 @gutter: 10px;
  .block-group { margin: -@gutter 0 0 -@gutter; }
  .block { padding: @gutter 0 0 @gutter; }
 }

 @media screen and (min-width: 761px) { 
  .wrapper div {
    width: (100% / 4);
  }
  @gutter: 10px;
  .block-group { margin: -@gutter 0 0 -@gutter; }
  .block { padding: @gutter 0 0 @gutter; }
 }
```

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to create a LESS Mixin so that I can reuse it to create many grids in a page and specifying the number of colums and gutter as parameters.

I tried to change the code but I always get problems because of Extend.

Could someone, please, help me out in making this code a mixin?

I would like to be able to use something like this:

```
.wrapper_1 {

  @media screen and (max-width: 760px) { make(2, 8px) }

  @media screen and (min-width: 761px) { make(4, 12px) }

  &:extend(.block-group);

  div {
    &:extend(.block);
  }

}
```

And also another wrapper in the same page and do something similar:

```
.wrapper_2 {

  @media screen and (max-width: 760px) { make(4, 12px) }

  @media screen and (min-width: 761px) { make(8, 16px) }

  &:extend(.block-group);

  div {
    &:extend(.block);
  }

}
```

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: What do you want in the mixin? What problems did you have because of extend? I placed the media queries in the empty mixin you provided: http://codepen.io/helderdarocha/pen/lyIkB?editors=110 What else do you want it to do?

Comment: I just update my question to better explain what I was trying to do ... I wanted a more straight forward way to apply a grid to an element. It this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call your mixin within the context of `.wrapper` you won't have any `.block` and `.block-group` selectors, but `.wrapper .block` and `.wrapper .block-group` and your `:extend` will not match anything. You could pass the selector as a parameter to the mixin, but the `extend` will also not match interpolated variables. Also, you need to match top-level `.block` and `.block-group`, so it even if it did match variables it wouldn't work anyway.

You can call the mixin as you suggested, and you can pass the name of the selector in a variable if you wish to apply a style to the div nested in your selector. So you could have this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .make(2; 8px; wrapper);
}
@media screen and (min-width: 761px) {
  .make(4; 12px; wrapper);
}
```

which is like you suggested, but passing the selector name as a parameter. Since the mixins are being called at top-level, the `.block` selectors will be top-level as well, and only the div selector will placed under the `.wrapper` context:

```
.make(@columns; @gutter; @selector) {
  .@{selector} {
    &:extend(.block-group);
    div:extend(.block) {
      width: (100% / @columns);
    }
  }
  .block-group { margin: -@gutter 0 0 -@gutter; }
  .block { padding: @gutter 0 0 @gutter; }
}
```

There is one problem with the mixin above. Since you are going to call it *inside* the media query, the *scope* of the `extend` will also be limited to the media-query. That's OK if you didn't have to extend any global selectors, but in your case you do. You can still use the mixin in the media-query as long as you use the `extend` pseudo-elements in your selectors instead of in the mixin:

```
.wrapper:extend(.block-group) {
  background-color: red;
  div:extend(.block) {
    background-color: green;
    img {
      display: block;
    ...
```

and remove them from the mixin:

```
.make(@columns; @gutter; @selector) {
  .@{selector} {
    div {
      width: (100% / @columns);
    }
  }
  .block-group { margin: -@gutter 0 0 -@gutter; }
  .block { padding: @gutter 0 0 @gutter; }
}
```

See [CodePen](http://codepen.io/helderdarocha/pen/sLuDl?editors=110)

Comment: I added a new wrapper to your example and a div in between ... Something strange happens: the second wrapper has a top padding and the middle div overlaps that green area. Any idea why? Here is the link: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/pgdEa

Comment: That's a padding. I'm not sure what your expected result is, but the order of padding/margin is **top right bottom left**. Your gutter happens on top and left. Is that what you want? The top one is not visible probably because it's negative margin is hiding it, but if you place some div before the first wrapper you will see it.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is:  `0 -@gutter 0 -@gutter`

Comment: The default behavior of PocketGrid is to use top-left negative margins to manage gutters, to allow having a full-page grid without external margins around. You can find explanations in the documentation: http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/docs/#gutters  You should not set a background on blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% certain of the exact output you seek, but I believe the following gives the essence of what you want, which should at least get you what you need to make what you desire.

```
.setGrid(
    @maxCols: 2; 
    @maxGutter: 8px; 
    @minCols: 4; 
    @minGutter: 12px; 
    @max-width: 760px
 )  {
    .setMedia(@cols; @gutter) {
        div {
            width: (100% / @cols);
        }
        .block-group { margin: -@gutter 0 0 -@gutter; }
        .block { padding: @gutter 0 0 @gutter; }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: @max-width) { 
        .setMedia(@maxCols; @maxGutter);
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: (1 + @max-width)) { 
        .setMedia(@minCols; @minGutter);
    }

  &:extend(.block-group);

  div {
    &:extend(.block);
  }
}

.wrapper_1 {
  .setGrid();
}

.wrapper_2 {
  .setGrid(4; 12px; 8; 16px);
}
```